# Unable to save the file in specified location using Autoit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit

Followed the below steps to save a file in desired location:

Step1: Save As window getting opened(with the default downloads location, with file name as DOC)

Step2: entering the file name as "D:\temp\sample.pdf" (which is getting entered in the edit bar)

Step3: clicking the save button (button clicked, file downloaded in the default location rather than the "D:\temp" location)

I have created an .exe with the below .au3 script

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",10)
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("Save As", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
Sleep(5000)
ControlClick("Save As", "", "Button1");
Sleep(5000)
```

On clicking save, it is getting saved in the default location rather than the specified location.

The below code, executing the script.

```
IO.popen('autoit_script.exe D:\temp') #Ruby Code
```

Is there a way to sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the software you are trying to automate but usually this happens because the software is not recognizing there is a change in the file save path box. The problem is in how ControlSetText works. Try using ControlSend with some error checking to make sure the file path you are try to set is getting put in right. Sometimes you have to play with a few different variations to see what works with the software you are automating. Here are two examples you can try:

Example one:

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]", "", 10)

If Not @error Then ;make sure the window was found

     $hWin = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:#32770]") ;get window handle

     ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1]) ;set text
     ControlFocus($hWin, "", "Edit1") ;just to make sure we have focus
     ControlSend($hWin, "", "Edit1", "{ENTER}")) ;should work like click button 1 but you will have to check

    ;better then a sleep
    $hTimer = TimerInit() ; Begin the timer and store the handle in a variable.
    Do
    Until WinExists($hWin) = 0 Or TimerDiff($hTimer) >= 10000
EndIf
```

Example two:

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]", "", 10)

If Not @error Then ;make sure the window was found

    $hWin = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:#32770]") ;get window handle

    While 1
        ControlSetText($hWin, "", "Edit1", "") ;just makes sure there is no text in the control text
        ControlFocus($hWin, "", "Edit1") ;just to make sure we have focus
        ControlSend($hWin, "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1])) ;set text using ControlSend

        If ControlGetText($hWin, "", "Edit1") = $CmdLine[1] Then ExitLoop ;makes sure that the control got ALL of the text before exiting loop
    WEnd

    ControlClick($hWin, "", "Button1");

    ;better then a sleep
    $hTimer = TimerInit() ; Begin the timer and store the handle in a variable.
    Do
    Until WinExists($hWin) = 0 Or TimerDiff($hTimer) >= 10000
EndIf
```

Comment: It works while clicking the Keyboard enter. Send("{ENTER}") instead of clicking on the save button in the dialog.

Comment: If the Send function works for you it might be a good idea to use ControlSend with {ENTER}. In the long run it will be much more reliable.